# Restrict users' behaviour in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I prohibit general users from using any requests except GET.

This should be applicable to terminal and web browser.

For example, general users should not be able to use the following command in terminal:

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://www.example.com:9200/customer/external/1?pretty'
```

Is this sufficient to achieve the goal? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/url-access-control.html  Or do I have to set up other parameters to reach the above goal.

Also how can I restrict general users from using GET request to obtain too much data. For example:

```
curl 'https://www.example.com:9200/dummyindex1/_search?q=*:*&pretty'
```

Thanks

Comment: This might help: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/current/configuring-rbac.html

Answer (score 0):

Shield is definitely a enterprise grade security product from elastic.[Shield](https://www.elastic.co/products/shield) comes with lot of security features along with authentication. It comes with authorization, SSL and LDAP integrations.

You can download the shield and start playing with it.You can directly jump to [Field and Document level security](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/current/setting-up-field-and-document-level-security.html) section where you can set access for the users to only  read the index based on authentication rules set by you.

These rules you can modify dynamically using the elastic REST api or you can configure them during deployment in the config files.

For Dynamically changing the authentication rules following the rest api.

```
POST /_shield/role/my_fls_role
{
  "indices": [
    {
      "names": [ "index1", "index2" ],
      "privileges": ["read"], 
      "fields": [ "title", "body" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This also support complex authentication rules where you can set the rules for the fields also for a particular roles

```
POST /_shield/role/customer_care
{
  "indices": [
    {
      "names": [ "*" ],
      "privileges": ["read"],
      "fields": [
            "issue_id",
            "description",
            "customer_handle",
            "customer_email",
            "customer_address",
            "customer_phone"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

You can configure multiple roles for multiple client apps for different access layers and if you are looking at more enterprise level security solutions you can configure these roles from LDAP as well , which is handled very beautifully by elastic as they cache the user credentials received from LDAP over the network to enhance performance.

Also if you are not looking for such grade security solutions, you can look at [nginx/apache reverse proxy](https://www.elastic.co/blog/playing-http-tricks-nginx) to authenticate the search requests before throwing it to cluster.